# Has anyone ever analyzed the type of questions vs the calendar?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that SO questions go in some sort of a cycle, with waves of newbie questions occurring for a week or two, then somewhat less naive questions for a few weeks.  Don't know if it would be related to school schedules or what, and don't have a clue as to how to analyze it, but it's a potentially interesting phenomenon (if my impressions are true).

Comment: There are certain periods during the school schedule that produce waves of such questions.

Comment: The calendar is stuck on September

Comment: We could start a study - drag and drop questions into bins, and sort those into dates, then count. Have fun implementing it! :)

Comment: We need to factor in the lunar phase as well. See if there is a full moon when all the crazy questions come out.

Comment: What about Friday, eh? It's always Friday in Iceland!

Comment: @random Eternal Friday?

Comment: I can certainly vouch that somewhere in the vicinity of 10 PM-midnight U.S. time every Sunday, the quality of iOS-related questions (and answers) takes a nosedive.

Comment: @Josh it's morning in India then - that's pretty certainly a factor (no offense to our plenty of *valued* contributors from India, of course!)

Comment: @Pekka: Yup, the start of the workweek on the other side of the world.

Answer (score 3):

[You can look at score and close count percentage](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71821/average-score-and-close-count-percentage-by-year-month) to see if there's a change month over month. I'll leave it to you to see if you can find a pattern month over month.

```
Avg_Score CloseCountPercentage month year 
--------- -------------------- ----- ---- 
161.2     0                    7     2008 
15.833602 0.0594607052316202   8     2008 
11.089009 0.0412796697626419   9     2008 
8.554738  0.0279286764235956   10    2008 
6.202574  0.0240381037433951   11    2008 
5.782043  0.0256190624513316   12    2008 
5.48562   0.0234699940582294   1     2009 
4.672511  0.0182930129350003   2     2009 
3.935539  0.0164080446298814   3     2009 
3.556143  0.0145408850192981   4     2009 
3.344831  0.0137977326968974   5     2009 
3.136148  0.0147454452579602   6     2009 
2.805524  0.0135439511587932   7     2009 
2.521266  0.0112299938102396   8     2009 
2.264269  0.00830870951698312  9     2009 
2.118176  0.00930170575692964  10    2009 
1.932727  0.00780955729101273  11    2009 
1.801787  0.00942167751819226  12    2009 
2.339628  0.00969013113977476  1     2010 
2.42432   0.0108960666278292   2     2010 
2.167111  0.0076658149094545   3     2010 
2.051308  0.00723337769804988  4     2010 
1.936797  0.0103513523540979   5     2010 
1.752515  0.0194672307348364   6     2010 
1.60956   0.019977574580313    7     2010 
1.610515  0.0192521901436012   8     2010 
1.552725  0.0191118693943995   9     2010 
1.437876  0.0208977167031714   10    2010 
1.441277  0.0206715505037316   11    2010 
1.345706  0.019308147598841    12    2010 
1.374392  0.0188202314493136   1     2011 
1.282048  0.0219543891527607   2     2011 
1.173771  0.0252765209834796   3     2011 
1.122367  0.0286872218690401   4     2011 
1.217903  0.032668700515726    5     2011 
1.130133  0.03313007023466     6     2011 
0.976285  0.0348148082527927   7     2011 
0.970282  0.0357422232578267   8     2011 
0.87364   0.0389819783115611   9     2011 
0.862309  0.0326890203813281   10    2011 
0.846628  0.037586483259458    11    2011 
0.804665  0.0388254737581243   12    2011 
0.764135  0.0366887325780297   1     2012 
0.65271   0.030412795818063    2     2012 
0.569333  0.0292261815429388   3     2012 
0.500984  0.0444985682783135   4     2012 
0.38183   0.0415258490881713   5     2012
```

Comment: Well, an autocorrelation or an FFT would tease out any rhythm.

Comment: Using a very crude autocorrelation, there appears to be a 4-month cycle in the CloseCountPercentage.  Can't analyze Avg_Score with this code since there's too much tilt.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger I've marked this answer as Community Wiki so feel free to add any analysis

Answer (score 2):

**A naive non-Bayesian approach (no NoSQL**)

Your application for running this analysis will be the StackExchange Data Explorer.

**Inquiry**
Is there correlation* between one or more cyclical time series and the frequency of "basic questions" submitted to StackOverflow?

**Preliminary requirements**
What is a "basic question"? Establish criteria for defining a "basic question". Here are some to consider:

```
Question is asked by user s.t. (reputation points < x) where 1 <= x <= 50
    OR [Question is asked by user s.t. (100 < reputation points < 102)  
       AND (User has other SE accounts) ]

    OR [ (Question is asked by user s.t. reputation < 500)   
       AND (time as SO user < 3 months)  
       AND (question is first question asked by that user for any given tag) ]

    AND [Duplicate prior open or closed questions > 2]
```

**Identify cyclical event**
What are some empirically observed tendencies?

1. Sunday night prior to homework due on Monday
2. End of semester projects postponed until the last minute by university (or post-graduate level...?) students
3. Any scheduled, repetitive event where there are high levels of participation by SO users, yet is **not** a proctored examination, but rather, a project type of activity.

Consider the global distribution of SO user base and prevalence of user location in deciding which events are plausible candidates for analysis.

- **Correlation is not causation!**
  Yes, I know. But it is a first step in gaining a preliminary understanding of the data and whether it is even feasible to answer the question. One needs to get acquainted with the data before analyzing it. We are subject matter experts, to some extent, as SO users, and even more so, as Meta SO users, which *should* help! But trying to formulate and run a preliminary analysis is needed for data profiling.

Also, consider the library of existing StackExchange Data Explorer queries. Browse through them, and maybe build off them for your initial data stratification.

**Analytic method**
If you get this far, and are able to identify one or more plausible time-series and criteria for selecting data, start with basic statistical methods such as ANOVA to look for correlations and trends. Watch out for colinearity.

Cross-post at Meta CrossValidated SE for further advice on statistical methodology.